# Globally unique random name for Images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

I am trying to write code for generating globally unique name for images that are to be uploaded by users from iOS app to server. The names should be randomly generated and should be unique so that the images are not overwritten/replaced.

Here's my code for generating random and unique strings:

```
+ (NSString *)generateRandNameWithLength:(int)len
{

    NSString *letters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%@0123456789", [HJUtilities generateUniqueApId]];
    NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: len];

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random() % [letters length]]];
    }

    return randomString;
}
```

Where:

```
+ (NSString *)generateUniqueApId
{
    NSString *appId = (__bridge NSString *) CFUUIDCreateString (NULL, CFUUIDCreate(NULL));

    return appId;
}
```

returns a UUID.

Now I'm not sure whether this is the correct code for generating globally unique strings. I don't know how to verify this to be certain that no user will overwrite another user's image.

Note: I'm using Amazon Web services for storage. And one common bucket will be used for all the images of all users. So, its required that images names should be unique.

Comment: use **%c** instead of **%C**

Comment: Looks good to me.  If you prefer, you can use `uuid_generate()` and `uuid_unparse()` which requires no memory management worries (I would expect `CFUUID` is based on the `uuid_xxx()` functions anyway): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/uuid_unparse.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/uuid_unparse

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thanks for the correction. I will look into the difference b/w %c and %C. I had copied this code from a post in here but don't remember the link now. I just added the CFUUID part to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for the code you have. All you need is the `CFUUIDCreateString` function. This will be unique across all users on all devices.

From the docs for `CFUUID`:

> UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers), also known as GUIDs (Globally Unique Identifiers) or IIDs (Interface Identifiers), are 128-bit values guaranteed to be unique. A UUID is made unique over both space and time by combining a value unique to the computer on which it was generated—usually the Ethernet hardware address—and a value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since October 15, 1582 at 00:00:00.

The code you have now is definitely not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @trojanfoe No. The OP is combing the UUID with a bunch of letters then grabbing random characters from the result.

Comment: The UUID function returns a string of 36 characters. Image names in this case are restricted to 14 characters.

Comment: The only way to convert a 128-bit UUID into a string of 14 characters would be to convert the UUID using base 1024. This of course would require the filenames to have lots of various Unicode characters. You need to allow for 36 character filenames if you want to ensure unique filenames.

Comment: @rmaddy A limitation of 14 characters is probably a limitation of 14 bytes, in which case, Unicode won't help.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. These are very helpful. I'm not sure why the restriction on file name length but the server team told me to do such.

Comment: Let the server team know that in order to meet the requirement for globally unique filenames, the filename length needs to be 36 (plus any possible extension).

Comment: You can get it down to 32 by stripping out the hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating it. Just get a UUID using `CFUUIDCreateString` and use that string. Adding extra layers of randomness isn't going to help. In fact, it's probably going to make things worse by increasing the chance of a name collision.

The only argument against using a UUID directly is that it may be possible to identify the source of the upload, since the UUID is (or can be) generated using device's MAC address, which is specific to the hardware. You won't be able to identify a user with nothing but a UUID, but you would be able to say "this collection of UUIDs came from the same device" or "this UUID came from this device". (See [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) for the various UUID formats and a discussion of this issue in section 4.5.)

If anonymity is a concern, running the UUID through a hash function, like SHA1 or MD5, would be good enough to make it unidentifiable.

Using a loop where you "add randomness" by mixing in random numbers is like shaking a dice for a few seconds versus an hour: the only difference is that you're rubbing sweat onto the dice.

Comment: "it may be possible to identify the source of the upload" Do you have a reference for this? I know that the MAC address might be used to produce UUIDs but is there evidence that it or other identifying parts can be retrieved from the UUID?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe The MAC address is all that I am referring to.

Comment: OK, but can it be retrieved from the UUID? ...or at least compared equal to other UUIDs?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Yes. The UUID format is specified by RFC 4122. The concern of being identifiable is explained in section 4.5. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

Answer (score 1):

There is a new class added in iOS 6.0

```
@interface NSUUID : NSObject <NSCopying, NSSecureCoding>
```

To simplify the memory management you for sure can use it

Comment: Thanks! but for now my target is iOS 5.0 and above.

Comment: I wrote my own `UUID` class, based on `uuid_xxx()` functions.  It'll take you 30 mins, tops.

Answer (score 0):

As far as a locally unique string — which you could use as part of the file name — this is handy:

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]
```